# How to monitor app resource usage on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am building an android application using Cordova and Ionic Framework. How can I monitor my app's resource usage? Like the CPU, ram and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Developer options -> Monitoring section -> Show CPU usage, Profile GPU rendering. For real-time memory monitoring you can use e.g. Android Studio's Memory Monitor panel for a connected device.